# I cannot find the restart count in KubernetesClient C#

Tags: c#, kubernetes

item.Status.ContainerStatuses.RestartCount doesn't exist. I cannot find the command. Reinstalling the nuget-package or updating it did not work either.

Down there I added the problem I have and the package I use. Sorry if my english is kinda rusty.

[image: the package I use]

[image: the problem I have]

Comment: Why do you think it should be there?

Comment: Based on a quick search through the github repo of that nuget it seems that there is such a thing as RestartCount (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/blob/8ab95b6b920e8a10b4c0122e09d158be2005aa15/src/KubernetesClient/generated/Models/V1ContainerStatus.cs). However, I'm not certain if it is exposed in any way in the client and moreover the documentation of this field suggests that the value is a bit dodgy to say the least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContainerStatuses` is a collection of `ContainerStatus`, not a `ContainerStatus` itself. You must choose from which container you want the `RestartCount`, per example:

```
 int restarts = item.Status.ContainerStatuses[0].RestartCount;
```